# Dnsqueryconfig returning junk characters!

Tags: windows, winapi, dns

Hi iam trying to retrieve the domain name of a machine using the following code

```
//if(FAILED(DnsQueryConfig(
  //  DnsConfigPrimaryDomainName_UTF8,
  //              FALSE,
  //              NULL,
  //              NULL,
  //              cszDomainName,
  //              &size
  // )))
  //{

  // //break;
  //}

  //LPWSTR lpcszContent = NULL;

  //if(int cbMultiByte = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, cszDomainName, -1,NULL,0))
  //{
  // lpcszContent = new wchar_t[cbMultiByte];
  // 
  // if(NULL!= lpcszContent)
  // {
  //  if(0 == MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, cszDomainName, -1, lpcszContent, cbMultiByte))
  //  {
  //   delete [] lpcszContent;
  //   break;
  //  }
  // }
  //}

  //if(NULL != lpcszContent)
  //{
  // cstrDomainName.Format(L"%s", lpcszContent);
  //
  // printf("Domain name UTF-8 character: %s", lpcszContent); 

  // delete lpcszContent;
  //}
```

The code works fine on an English machine.
But on a machine with Brazilian OS the domain name is retrieved as junk characters.

Is there anything wrong with the code?
Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you're querying the domain name in UTF-8 and then converting to wide characters?  Why not query the domain name in wide characters directly (DnsConfigPrimaryDomainName_W).